# Unable to telnet to a VPC instance - AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to connect to a particular port from another AWS instance. Getting connection refused.

In the AWS instance, I have added port 11626 in inboud rules under security groups. Also, I can check port 11626 is listening and I can do self telnet using localhost.

However when I do a self telnet using public/private IP, it is saying connection refused. Is the natting between Public and private IP missing? If yes How do i map these IP?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting the AWS instance over the public Internet? Also, how are you connecting to the instance?

Basically, to be able to connect to AWS instance, you need to have the following:

1. A **Public** IP assigned to the AWS EC2 instance. You can't connect to an instance using **Private** IP unless you have VPN which is generally set up for an organisation.
2. Open the desired port (in your case port 11626). You can open this desired port for the entire public (0.0.0.0/0) or you can specify **public** IP address in the security group.

If you already created your EC2 instance without getting a public IP address assigned, you can request for allocation of a new Elastic IP address and assign it to your EC2 instance and connect using the Elastic IP address.